# hhvm create file using FTP

Tags: php, facebook, ftp, hhvm

I have been trying to use HHVM to create files over ftp. As far as my understanding is; I the standard FTP Functions that are in PHP the `ftp_` functions aren't supported in HHVM.
As I have spent the best part of a day trying to hack `fopen` over an ftp url and have made no progress I'm running out of ideas!

Comment: Use a userland FTP implementation; [PEAR Net_FTP](http://pear.php.net/package/Net_FTP/redirected), or upgradephps drop-in [ftp_* functions](http://fossil.include-once.org/upgradephp/artifact/900314894ee45d3b160a21641b702b982f246d8c), or github/[suin-ftp](https://github.com/suin/php-ftp-client). Though cURL also provides FTP uploads if HHVMs stream wrapper doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HHVM currently does not support neither [FTP stream wrappers](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/2108) nor [FTP extension](http://docs.hhvm.com/manual/en/function.ftp-connect.php), so you must use userland PHP FTP implementation.

Comment: For the record, I used a hand written cURL that was a quick and dirty implementation of the underlying logic of the ftp_ functions in native php. It did the trick, though it's not as robust as a proper implementation.